# How to extend facebook API rate limit?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-messenger, messenger

I send to my customers many messages by messenger API.
But after some time i receive error: Calls to this api have exceeded the rate limit.

Is there any option to extend this limit? Does facebook have some payment plans (market in Poland) to extend it?

I use API (https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/) endpoint: 'me/messages'.

The error is

```
"error":{"message":"(#613) Calls to this api have exceeded the rate limit.","type":"OAuthException","code":613
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, there is no paid option.